# RegEx to verify: abc123(30x2) and variations there of

Tags: regex

I'm using  to develop a regex in order to verify a pattern that will match the following:

```
abc123
Ab3TF56G
BD356-2

abc123(3x4)
Ab3TF56G(24x37)
BD356-2(105x04)

abc123 (3x4)
Ab3TF56G (24x37)
BD356-2 (105x04)

abc123(3x4x10)
Ab3TF56G(24x37x3)
BD356-2(105x04x14)

abc123 (3x4x10)
Ab3TF56G (24x37x3)
BD356-2 (105x04x14)
```

I'm admittedly terrible at RegEx, but am following the guide at: www.regexr.com, and have come up with this so far: 
`([A-Za-z0-9])\((\d[x^)]\d+)\)+`

Unfortunately, it stops working when I start trying to account for the possible dash and parathentises.

• The alpha-numeric set can be any length

• That sequence can, but does not require a dash followed by an integer

• Which can also be followed by a open & close parentheses with integers separated by the "x" character (basically dimensions)

Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**
In addition, the following should fail:

```
abc123 (3x4x10)shs
sdlk234(3x)
sdlk234(3x0)
sdlk234-2 (3x)333
Ab3T F56G
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\s?(\([\dx]+\))?
```

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/pU9oR4/1

Here is a graphical representation: https://www.debuggex.com/r/uVGo8mrIUYhXHxjP

**EDIT**

After your shouldn't match examples it turns out a bit more harder, so your new pattern should be:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\b)([\s\d-])?(\((?:(?!0)[\d]+)((x(?:(?!0\b)[\d]+))(x(?:(?!0\b)[\d]+))?)\))?$
```

**edited again**
See it working here: https://www.debuggex.com/r/dxPPbPw0mUKQPRWg

I also add the validation so it didn't match:

```
sdlk234(3x0x0)
sdlk234(3x1x0)
sdlk234(0x1x1)
```

Following your logic of dimensions

Comment: Close; I've added some cases that should fail but don't to the original question.

Comment: sorry, tried to add it to the reply but the formatting was sub-optimal. Added the failing cases to the original question as an edit.

Comment: That's pretty intense! Unfortunately, it fails on the first three instances (the ones with out the parentheses)

Answer (score 0):

[101 Regexp Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jP2tS7/1)

```
^[\w-]+\s*(\((?!0\b)\d+(x(?!0\b)\d+)+\))?$
```

`(?!0\b)`: Negative Lookahead ,make sure that after it can't be `0\b`

`\b`:assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)